# How to add dynamically images with a v-for in vuetify and firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to dynamically load the images with a from firebase store (I get the URL from firestore and store in an array ).

But neither the `:src='require("user.documents.selfie.url")'` nor `:src='user.documents.selfie.url'` works. I've tried tons of stackoverflow answers, but no success.

Template PUG:

```pug
v-col.col-3(v-for='(user, i) in users' :key='i')
  v-card(max-width='374')
  v-img(:src='require("user.documents.selfie.url")'  height='100')
```

Load user object from Firebase Firestore.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    const ref = db.collection('users');
    ref.get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        user.id = doc.id;
        this.users.push(user);
      });
    });
  },
  }
```

ERROR:

```
> This dependency was not found:

* user.documents.selfie.url in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader", "cacheIdentifier":"1a565fa8-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/pug-plain-loader!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--20-0!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Approval/BaseApproval.vue?vue&type=template&id=6cdee0a0&lang=pug&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save user.documents.selfie.url
```

What could i've been doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you use `:src='user.documents.selfie.url'` what error do you have?

Comment: what you pass to `:src ` is link or path?

Comment: @Mohsen It's an URL path for firebase storage.

Comment: @HansFelixRamos If I use :src='user.documents.selfie.url' i got this in the browser console and the whole v-for section disappear. 

webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1887 TypeError: Cannot read property 'selfie' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I believe I find the issue but can't resolve.

For some reason, when I store the `data()` object from Firestore into an memory array, returns a promise. Then when I try to fetch outside like the methods the object returns "pending"

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    db.collection('users').get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        user.id = doc.id;
        this.users = doc.data();
        console.log(this.users.status); // here the the log works.
      });
    });
  },
  methods: {
    imageUrl() {
      console.log(this.users.status); // Here the log return "Pending";
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with pug, but it seems to me that the string is not interpreted correctly

I don't think you need a second set of quotes for `require`. Can you try:

`v-img(:src='require(user.documents.selfie.url)'`

But the require is for module request, if the `user.documents.selfie.url` includes the full (absolute) path, then `:src='user.documents.selfie.url'` should work

Comment: unfortunately the :src='user.documents.selfie.url' doesn't work. Out of Vuetify, works fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "Out of Vuetify, works fine"? Sounds maybe like a matter of it working only in dev server.

Comment: out of <v-app> </v-app> tag. 

I had bulma css only before and it was working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `require` when the address can be resolved at compile time.

For runtime paths you shouldn't use `require`, you can just use the variable name

```
v-col.col-3(v-for='(user, i) in users' :key='i')
  v-card(max-width='374')
  v-img(:src='user.documents.selfie.url'  height='100')
```